# How can I update my xCode to iOS 7 simulator if I have Mac OSx 10.7.4

Tags: ios, ios7

I went to iTunes to try to update my xCode but it told me that 10.8.4 is required.

Is there any workaround? I never updated my full OS before. How involved is the process on a mac?

Thanks!

Comment: Just update your OS. It will download Mac OS from the Mac App Store, you click install and your Mac does everything else for you. It's pretty easy. Just remember to backup your system before updating so you can go back in case you don't like Mountain Lion.

Comment: Xcode 5 needs OS X Mountain Lion, which is $19 in the App Store. If you wait a few more weeks, OS X Mavericks will be released, and you can save a couple bucks.

Comment: @Scott thanks, just googled Mavericks. But how do people get it free if it is new? Would it be through a beta program?

Comment: They get it because they're members of the OSX Developer program (the payed the $99).  Just upgrade your OS to Mountain Lion, it's cheap and easy.

Comment: @MattS. thanks, just so I understand, is the $99 you are referring to the fee to become an iOS developer and get xCode. I already pay that so would I be able to get the Mavericks OS for free? And does that discount not apply to 10.8.4 update?

Comment: @Genadinik: If you are part of the Mac Developer Program (different from iOS Developer Program, but also $99 a year), you get it for free now, but you'll likely have to pay later. If you are not in the Mac Developer Program, you can't get Mavericks yet.